# About fundumental group of wedge sum.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Exercise form  algebraic topology hatcher 1.1.18. Using Lemma $1.15,$ show that if a space $X$ is obtained from a path-connected subspace $A$ by attaching a cell $e^{n}$ with $n \geq 2,$ then the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ induces a
surjection on $\pi_{1} .$ Apply this to show:

(a) The wedge sum $S^{1} \vee S^{2}$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$.

(b) For a path-connected CW complex $X$ the inclusion map $X^{1} \hookrightarrow X$ of its 1 -skeleton induces a surjection $\pi_{1}\left(X^{1}\right) \rightarrow \pi_{1}(X) .$ [For the case that $X$ has infinitely many cells, see Proposition A.1 in the Appendix.

I can show the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ induces a
surjection on $\pi_{1} .$ but I can't Apply this to show "a" and "b"

Comment: For $a)$ note that $S^1$ is a retract of $S^1\vee S^2$.

Comment: @Tyrone . Why? How we can show this?

Comment: Think of $S^1\vee S^2$ as a subspace of $S^1\times S^2$ and restrict the projection to $S^1$.

Answer (score 2):

a) $S^1\vee S^2$ is formed by attaching a $2$-cell to $S^1$ with a constant map on its boundary, so the inclusion $i\colon S^1 \hookrightarrow S^1 \vee S^2$ induces a surjection $i_*\colon\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \to \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^2)$ by the given result. To show $i_*$ is also an injection, observe there is a canonical retraction $r\colon S^1 \vee S^2 \to S^1$ given by taking the identity on the $S^1$ summand and a constant map on the $S^2$ summand; then injectivity follows by functoriality. (Note this injectivity is true in general: a wedge sum $A\vee B$ always has retractions to $A$ and $B$, so the inclusions of $A$ and $B$ into the wedge sum induce injections for any covariant functor to a concrete category, in particular $\pi_1$.)

For b) it's just a repeated application of the given result since $X$ is made out of $X^1$ by attaching cells of dimension $\geq 2$. You can prove it by induction on the cells, but if $X$ has uncountably many cells you need transfinite induction.